# Delphi Chromium Embedded DCEF3 - rendering problems

Tags: delphi, rendering, chromium

I'm using Delphi Chromium Embedded DCEF3 in a application, and I have a strange behaviour installing the application on different PCs, in particular in rendering of web page when program executes instruction

```
crm.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(URL);
```

On all PCs where we installed it works correctly (page is rendered correctly) except on a PC where browser's window is not rendered (it remains blank) after LoadUrl (but the URl is correct).

What may be the reason ?

Comment: Have you checked if network cable is plugged in properly?

Comment: Yes, all ok, but in any case the url is a 'local' url, so this is not important.

Comment: My question is: DCEF3 requires some particular version of system libraries (f.i. DirectX, ...) ?

Comment: I have verified, the URL is loaded, but the page is not rendered for some reason by Chromium Embedded. I have tried also to do a RePaint after loading, but no result... I repeat: this problem occurs on a customer's PC, on the other ones it's all ok.

Comment: No one has observed this problem ?

Comment: I have the same problem and it doesn't work as expected. Try to make the TChromium object larger. It will load the page but when you resize it you will see it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off "Accelerated Compositing" in Chromium Options.